# How to pair up a list of list with a list?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have two lists:

```
xy = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
z = [1,3,5]
```

I want to merge them to get:

```
xyz = [[1,2,1],[3,4,3],[5,6,5]]
```

or

```
xyz = [(1,2,1),(3,4,3),(5,6,5)]
```

Here is how I achieve this:

```
for i,lst in enumerate(xy):
    lst.append(z[i])
xy
```

Is there any neater way to do it without using the for loop or something?

Comment: You clearly cannot do it without a loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Python 3.5+, you can make use of [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/):

```
xyz = [(*a, b) for a, b in zip(xy, z)]
```

This also uses [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to make it a simple one-liner.

---

If you do not want to use a `for` loop at all, there is actually a way using functional programming and [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), but this is probably not the best way to go (Python does not favor functional programming):

```
xyz = map(lambda a, b: a + [b], xy, z)
```

Answer (score 3):

This may be a neater way:

```
Ret = [a + [b] for a, b in zip(xy, z)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Short *list comprehension* with `enumerate` function:

```
result = [l+[z[k]] for k,l in enumerate(xy)]
print(result)
```

The output:

```
[[1, 2, 1], [3, 4, 3], [5, 6, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest list-comprehensions for readability:

```
[a + [b] for a, b in zip(xy, z)]
```